# Parse Json to List

Tags: json, windows-phone-8, json.net

I want to parse a json to List how can we do that. I have tried the following code but it didnt worked

```
Dictionary<string, object> pGateways=(Dictionary<string,object>)Json.JsonParser.FromJson(jsonString);

List<object> creditOptions = new List<object>();
creditOptions = (List<object>)pGateways;
```

And after getting it int list i want to loop through it

Here is my sample json

```
{
    "MessageCode": "CS2009",
    "Status": "Y",
    "ErrorCode": "0",
    "ErrorDescription": "Success",
    "account": 
     {
        "card": 
        [
            {
                "cardend": "asd",
                "token": "aads",
                "cardstart": "asdad",
                "accounttype": "asda",
                "cardnetwork": "as",
                "issuer": "asd",
                "customername": "a",
                "expdate": "04/2018"
            },
            {
                "cardend": "asda",
                "token":"adssadsa",
                "cardstart": "asd",
                "accounttype": "asd",
                "cardnetwork": "asd",
                "issuer": "asda",
                "customername": "asd",
                "expdate": "03/2016"
            }
        ],
        "bank": []
    }
}
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

The best option could be to use the [JsonConvert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base?lq=1) in order to parse `Json` into a `List`.

Reference:  [JSON Parsing in Windows Phone](http://developer.nokia.com/community/discussion/showthread.php/248076-JSON-Parsing-in-Windows-Phone-using-C)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Json.Net.

To install Json.NET use NugetGallery : [Json.net Nugets Gallery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

And you can use [json2Csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) for generate c# classes from json

Answer (score 0):

The JSON string you posted is not suitable for straight-forward deserialization to List. The easiest thing to do is use the online  [JSON 2 CSharp](http://json2csharp.com/)  tool to generate classes and deserialize the json string to it. Here is an example of the generated classes:

```
public class Card
{
    public string cardend { get; set; }
    public string token { get; set; }
    public string cardstart { get; set; }
    public string accounttype { get; set; }
    public string cardnetwork { get; set; }
    public string issuer { get; set; }
    public string customername { get; set; }
    public string expdate { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public List<Card> card { get; set; }
    public List<object> bank { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string MessageCode { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string ErrorDescription { get; set; }
    public Account account { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the logic for deserialization:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonStr);
```

where the `jsonStr` variable holds the json string you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) tool to generate classes and deserialize the JSON string to list.

Here is the Classes generated from your JSON string.

```
 public class Card
{
    public string cardend { get; set; }
    public string token { get; set; }
    public string cardstart { get; set; }
    public string accounttype { get; set; }
    public string cardnetwork { get; set; }
    public string issuer { get; set; }
    public string customername { get; set; }
    public string expdate { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public List<Card> card { get; set; }
    public List<object> bank { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string MessageCode { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string ErrorDescription { get; set; }
    public Account account { get; set; }
}
```

and Deserialize your JSON object using  JsonConvert,

Suppose `e.result` is your JSON string then

```
 var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
 foreach (var blog in rootObject.Card)
        {
           //access your data like this- `blog.cardend;` or `blog.token;` 
        }
```